# Calling a dll function from JS XPCOM

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xpcom

I wanted to know if the XPCOM JS can call an external dll function?

I have a dll that exposes certain functions. I want my XPCOM JS function to be able to call the dll function. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you cannot call external dlls from JS unless the dlls are XPCOM components take a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_build_a_binary_XPCOM_component_using_Visual_Studio
then u can use JS to call the functions exposed by the dlls by defining them in the XPT

edit a tutorial : http://nerdlife.net/building-a-c-xpcom-component-in-windows/

Comment: Does XPCOM provide any interface that would help us load a dll file in JS XPCOM itself ?

Comment: In case it doesn't how should I go about it ? I will have to write an XPCOM dll that will expose the functions of my dll to my extension and then use the JS XPCOM file to call the exposed function ? Basically I end up with 2 XPCOM components, 1 written in JS and another in C++.

Comment: Note that it's much easier to use JS C-types if you plan on supporting Firefox 4 or later.

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox 4 and later, you can use [JS C-Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/js-ctypes) to accomplish this.